# In Spyder how do you run a python script in the projects folder from another script

Tags: python, spyder

I am wondering how I can run/load a python script containing all the imports needed and functions for the main script from the main script. I cant figure out how to do it, runfile works in the console but not the script itself. When I try stuff like that is just says runfile is undefined.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You can save a python file to here: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib (Or where ever your python is) called "mysetup.py" and have the contents of the file as the import commands that you want like this.

[image]

Then in your other python file you can can import the name of your file like this

```
import mysetup
```